# PJSIP/PJSUA2 - stream AudioMediaPlayer / AudioMediaRecorder

Tags: c++, audio, streaming, pjsip

According to [PJSIP/PJSUA2 documentation](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/PJSUA2Doc.pdf), the way to retrieve/send audio data is to use AudioMediaRecorder/AudioMediaPlayer which write/read data to/from file.

Is there a way to do that with streams and buffers?

Comment: like JMR said, it seems possible to do such things using [pjmedia_aud_stream](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/structpjmedia__aud__stream.htm) (more info [here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__audio__device__api.htm))

Comment: I updated my answer according, to you comment.

Comment: if my answer helped in some way you could accept the answer as coorect.

Answer (score -2):

Do you want something like this http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/page_pjmedia_samples_playfile_c.htm ?

--Updated--

The solution as suggested by the user:

http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__audio__device__api.htm

To start the audio stream:

```
status = pjmedia_aud_stream_start(stream);
```

To stop the stream:

```
status = pjmedia_aud_stream_stop(stream);
```

And to destroy the stream:

```
status = pjmedia_aud_stream_destroy(stream);

Info: The following shows how to retrieve the capability value of the stream (in this case, the current output volume setting).
// Volume setting is an unsigned integer showing the level in percent.
unsigned vol;
status = pjmedia_aud_stream_get_cap(stream,
PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_VOLUME_SETTING,
&vol);
Info: And following shows how to modify the capability value of the stream (in this case, the current output volume setting).
// Volume setting is an unsigned integer showing the level in percent.
unsigned vol = 50;
status = pjmedia_aud_stream_set_cap(stream,
PJMEDIA_AUD_DEV_CAP_OUTPUT_VOLUME_SETTING,
&vol);
```

Comment: No, the entire point is to retrieve/send audio data using streams instead of files. Thank you anyway!

Comment: http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__audio__device__api.htm see this, maybe can help you. "Working with audio streams"